# Pods stuck in ContainerCreating with "failed to assign an IP address to container"

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

Multiple pods of a 600 pod deployment stuck in `ContainerCreating` after a rolling update with the message:

> Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc =
>   NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod  network: add cmd:
>   failed to assign an IP address to container

What I have tried:

- Upgraded to v1.12 on EKS and CNI 1.5.0.  [This issue was closed stating CNI 1.5.0 solved the issue.](https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/issues/123)  It did not for us.  In another thread [leaking ENIs was blamed](https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/issues/69) but was also closed due to CNI upgrade.
- [Installed cni-metrics-helper](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/cni-metrics-helper/) and this is a snapshot of the output:

```
maxIPAddresses, value: 759.000000
ipamdActionInProgress, value: 1.000000
addReqCount, value: 16093.000000
awsAPILatency, value: 564.000000
delReqCount, value: 32337.000000
eniMaxAvailable, value: 69.000000
assignIPAddresses, value: 558.000000
totalIPAddresses, value: 682.000000
eniAllocated, value: 69.000000
```

Do the CNI metrics output suggest there's an issue?  Seems like there are enough IPs.

What else can I try to debug?

Comment: do you have DNS service running?

Comment: @Vishrant Yes.  Running kube-dns deployment with 3 replicas.

Comment: What instance type are you using?

Comment: @ClaesMogren t2.large

Comment: Problem was temporarily solved by simply deleting the pods that were stuck in `ContainerCreating`.  Kubernetes should be handling this though.  Still interested in proper way of upgrading CNI.

Comment: We've upgraded to EKS 1.12 and CNI 1.5.0 and STILL having this problem.

Comment: Now coredns is running

Comment: The only thing i see is that all ENI have been allocated and nothing is left, though IPs are still available.

Comment: Its sometimes because of the limitation of the type of the instances and since  the IP are associated with worker node configuration if depends upon how much it can support. If you are running on most recent CNI I recommend going to a higher type machine

Comment: How many nodes do you have? I am not familiar with which CNI provider EKS uses, but some CNI providers allocate a /24 per node, meaning you can only have a maximum of 254 pods per node

Comment: @chaosaffe 23 nodes...

Comment: Clearly not the issue here then I guess, assuming the pods are being distributed across the nodes in a somewhat sane fashion.

Comment: Checking in, this is still an issue

Comment: Does EKS have sufficient privileges to AssignPrivateIP addresses for the pods?

Answer (score 10):

It seems that you reached maximum number of IP addresses in your subnet what can suggest such thing in [documentation](https://github.com/liwenwu-amazon/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s-1/blob/metrics1/docs/troubleshooting.md#tip-make-sure-there-are-enough-enis-and-ips-for-pods-in-the-cluster):

> maxIPAddress: the maximum number of IP addresses that can be used for
>   Pods in the cluster. (assumes there is enough IPs in the subnet).

Please take a look also on [maxUnavailable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#max-unavailable) and [maxSurge](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#max-surge) parameters which controls how many PODs appear during rolling upgrade - maybe your configuration assumes that during rolling upgrade you will have over 600 PODs (like 130%) and that hit limits of your AWS network.